# React Native: How to navigate from inside the NavigationContainer?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have a component in my Navigation.tsx which controls the routes within my application. The component sits inside one of my Stack.Screen's under *headerRight* . Im trying to navigate to a different screen when the component is clicked. However, im unable to get that working for this particular component. Routing outside my Navigation file works perfectly fine, but not within.

Im unable to figure out what i am missing or what needs to be changed.

Code below: headerRight under ItemDetails

```
export default function Navigation( { navigation }) {
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MyTheme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    colors: {
      ...DefaultTheme.colors,
      background: '#FFF',
    }
}

return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">

            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={({route}) => ({
                headerShown: false,
            })}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='CartDetails' component={CartDetails}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="ItemDetails" component={ItemDetails} options={({route}) => ({
                title: false,
                headerTitle: false,
                headerBackTitleVisible: false,
                headerTransparent: true,
                headerShadowVisible: false,
                headerRight: () => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('CartDetails')}}>
                        <CartIcon />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ),
                headerBackImage: () => (
                    
                        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff', borderRadius: '50%', marginLeft: 15, marginBottom: 5}}>
                            <Entypo name="chevron-small-left" size={30} color="#37BD6B"/>
                        </View>
                )
            })} />

        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)
```

}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

Rather than passing headerRight an argument, passing it to 'option' gives you the correct result.

```
 options={({route, navigation}) => ({ 
                title: false,
                headerTitle: false,
                headerBackTitleVisible: false,
                headerTransparent: true,
                headerShadowVisible: false,
                headerRight: () => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CartDetails')}>
                        <CartIcon />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ),
                headerBackImage: () => (
                    
                        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#ffffff', borderRadius: '50%', marginLeft: 15, marginBottom: 5}}>
                            <Entypo name="chevron-small-left" size={30} color="#37BD6B"/>
                        </View>
                )
            })}  />
```

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation provides the `navigation` object as an argument to the header callbacks. You can take it from there.

```
  headerRight: ({ navigation }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('CartDetails')}}>
      <CartIcon />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ),
```

Comment: Error given back on 'navigate'. 'Property 'navigate' does not exist on type 'HeaderButtonProps''

Comment: Sorry, you have to destructure it. Edited answer.

Comment: Returns uncaught error:

Undefined is not an object navigation.navigate